# JavaFX : Barchart with multiple (2) y axis

Tags: javafx

I would like to create a JavaFX barchart with takes 2 y-axis, since the series-values are too wide apart, resulting in second series not showing off properly in the chart.

I have dummed-down the code to its very basics, for the purpose of this question:

```
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart;
    import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
    import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
    import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;


    public class MultiAxisTryout extends Application {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }

        @Override
        public void start(Stage stage) {

            stage.setTitle("Bar Chart Multi Example");

            final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
            final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
            final BarChart bc =
                    new BarChart(xAxis,yAxis);
            bc.setTitle("Cost &  Delta by JV");
            xAxis.setLabel("JV");

            XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
            series1.setName("Cost");
            XYChart.Series series2 = new XYChart.Series();
            series2.setName("Delta");


            series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("1000000", 25000));
            series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("1200000", 30000));
            series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("1000000", 22));
            series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("1200000", 86));

            Scene scene  = new Scene(bc  ,1800,1000);

            scene.setFill(null);
            bc.setAnimated(false);
            bc.getData().addAll(series1,series2);

            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();

        }
    }
```

The result looks like this :

[image]

As you can see, the second series is not showing off very well in the barchart, so it would be nice to have a second y-axis with its own scale, showing off better in the barchart.

Is this possible in JavaFx ?

Comment: See _Multiple Axis Demos_ in the [tag:jfreechart] gallery.

Comment: Have a look here : https://github.com/JKostikiadis/MultiAxisCharts , it's one of my own projects which is still under development but it does exactly what you want.